# pointer to functions vs simpler switch in high speed audio programming

Tags: c++, audio

I am looking at simplifying some class structures by combining a number of classes and either

a.  having a simple switch statement, using variables assigned on initialisation of the class, that changes some of the function behaviour within the class.

or

b. using functions pointers to define different behaviours in a class.  These pointers would be assigned in the class initialisation.

In audio, which requires speed, a. is a lot cleaner looking and maybe safer than b. 
My question is- Is a switch statement(a.) that much more slower than function pointers(b.)?
Is there a simpler method, like a template type class which changes according to an initialisation variable, but has the same input variables for all variations or am I wishing too much?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer will vary a lot with the hardware you intend to run the program on, so the only real way to find out is to test it yourself:  come up with an appropriate performance test, then rewrite the code each way and see which way executes faster.  (You're going to have to do that eventually anyway, to make sure that your changes actually improved things, so you might as well do it up front)

Comment: That said, you'll probably get better performance by avoiding both function pointers and switch statements as much as possible, especially if they are things that would get called every sample.  Try to hoist those constructs out of your innermost per-sample loops if possible.

Comment: Hi, The classes are not in the audio loop.  They are for slider behaviour, which is on a slower timer.  I will do performance testing. Thanks

Comment: Slider as in the GUI widget?  I'm not sure I'd call that "high speed audio programming", rather that's GUI programming.  Make sure to keep your audio processing in a separate thread from your GUI handling, so that your GUI routines won't hold off the audio routines.  Assuming you've done that, the efficiency of your GUI routines isn't all that important.

Comment: Yes it is GUI, but a lot of metering like interaction is happening in the GUI slider paint event along with a huge number of sliders.  The thread is separate. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I am still dreaming of a set function based on class init variable.  The number of sub classes I have ended up with is ridiculous.   I am cleaning up my code.  Over one hundred sliders for an eq, multi band compressor, compressor, pitch shifter, delay, reverb and limiter all in one.  All the sliders have varied pop up windows, different type dials, etc

Answer (score -1):

Since this is C++, it seems like the obvious answer is "c": use [virtual functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

Your (a) vs. (b) question is almost impossible to answer, mostly because such questions should only be answered with a profiler.  Beware premature optimization.  Trying to be tricky for the sake of speed can be problematic because compiler writers and hardware designers tend to optimize for common idioms.  If you do weird stuff then you'll miss out on that.

Comment: Hi I am already using copious virtual functions, but this is a good idea.  I could define these functions at the end of the long chain of classes, but would that still require a different class for each virtual function? Thanks